# Exchange 2010 - Hybrid Office 365, need to update admin identity password

Tags: exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, exchange-hybrid

We have two on-premise Exchange 2010 servers, and one Exchange Online (O365 for Business).

I've changed the password for our O365 Global Admin account (which is also used to connect the hybrid set-up) and now when I jump on to our On premise server, I can't view mailbox, distribution group etc through the EMC.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on where I update the credentials for the Administrator Identity within our on-premise Exchange server for our Remote server?

Do I need to use Powershell for this?

Regards,
Vas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the EAC, right-click the top node and just re-add the O365 connection as a new forest.  It will ask you for credentials to connect.